# Regular expression match from right direction

Tags: python, regex, reverse

Normally, we use regular expression match from left to right direction. I want to know whether there is some switch that can be used to match from the right to left in python?
Or is this feature embedded in any other language?

e.g.

```
abcd1_abcd2
```

If given regular expression `abcd`, it will match two `abcd` strings. What I want is to put the last match at first, thus matching in reverse direction.

Comment: What switch and what was in *normally*?

Comment: what prevents you from reversing resulting list?

Comment: generally the reason you'd match from right to left (at least in .NET) is for performance reasons, and not to actually return a list of matches backwards. for instance if you have a very complicated expression that can result in lots of backtracking, but your match ends with a simple string 'XYZ' then the parser will eliminate a lot of wasted processing by working backwards and looking for XYZ first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse the list as proposed by @SilentGhost:

```
import re

for s in reversed(re.findall('abcd.', 'abcd1_abcd2')):
    print s
```

Comment: in fact i need use finditer,but it was a yield expression,so i use [for match in finditer(obj)][::-] instead